# Execute Callback after hibernate transaction was done

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

i need to execute indexation method after hibernate finish its transaction.
All calls to hibernate are wrapped into DAO's classes. By example the save is fired this way :

```
@Override
public final PK create(final T newInstance) {
    return (PK) this.getSession().save(newInstance);
}
```

I want to know how i can inject some code to execute as callback of transactions create, update, delete.

Comment: I think i have to use the Interceptor's hibernate interface, am i right ?